# How to split a string into a javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I have a string

> "B & D & P && D & P && B & C"

I'd like to split the string into a Javascript array by using the & or && as separators in order to get something like

"B, D, P, D, P, B, C"

I was wondering how I would approach this situation. Thanks!

Comment: what is the difference between `&` and `&&` separators? are these the only ones you will have?

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex.

```js
const str = "B & D & P && D & P && B & C";

console.log(str.split(/[\s&]+/g));
```

Comment: `,` is not needed, OP don't have a requirement to split by `,` also.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by using regex. Try the following code

```js
var str = 'B & D & P && D & P && B & C';
matches = str.match(/[^&]+/g);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Maybe exclude whitespaces also: `/[^&\s*]+/g`

Comment: @dfsq yes it is a good suggestion. Thanks.